# ionic angular, error con @angular/animations

Tags: nodejs, ionic, ionic-framework

tengo un problema con una app que estoy intentando hacer en ionic, me pasa que cuando ejecuto "npm install @angular/animations" me sale el error que está en la imagen.

Versión de ionic: 6.20.1

Versión de node.js: V16.17.0

[image: @angular/animations]

Comment: Intenta eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` y el archivo `package-lock.json`. Luego ejecuta el comando `npm install`. Posteriormente `npm install @angular/animations`

Answer (score 0):

Elimina la carpeta `node modules`, y ejecuta

```
npm install --force
```